# Plotting a rasterio raster on a Cartopy GeoAxes

Tags: cartopy, rasterio

I've seen a few other questions on this topic, but the library has changed enough that the answers to those no longer seem to apply.

Rasterio [used to include an example](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/blob/b9f34ee559039239c7c0c97bd911b466701a39cd/examples/Data%20visualization.ipynb) for plotting a rasterio raster on a Cartopy GeoAxes. The example went roughly like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import rasterio
from rasterio import plot

import cartopy
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

world = rasterio.open(r"../tests/data/world.rgb.tif")

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 12))
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.InterruptedGoodeHomolosine())
ax.set_global()
plot.show(world, origin='upper', transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), interpolation=None, ax=ax)

ax.coastlines()
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.BORDERS)
```

However, this code no longer draws the raster. Instead, I get something like this:

[image: map without raster (incorrect output)]

It should look like this:

[image: map with raster (old, correct output)]

When I asked about this in the rasterio issues tracker, they told me the example was deprecated (and deleted the example). Still, I wonder if there's some way to do what I'm trying to do. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

I think you may want to read the data to a `numpy.ndarray` and plot it using `ax.imshow`, where `ax` is your `cartopy.GeoAxes` (as you have it already). I offer an example of what I mean, below.

I clipped a small chunk of Landsat surface temperature and some agricultural fields for this example. Get them on this [drive link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1POFAAK1pxiCT5CwUeUPUbG5pyFzskoCy?usp=sharing).

Note fields are in WGS 84 (epsg 4326), Landsat image is in UTM Zone 12 (epsg 32612), and I want my map in Lambert Conformal Conic. Cartopy makes this easy.

```
import numpy as np
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from cartopy.io.shapereader import Reader
from cartopy.feature import ShapelyFeature
import rasterio
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def cartopy_example(raster, shapefile):
    with rasterio.open(raster, 'r') as src:
        raster_crs = src.crs
        left, bottom, right, top = src.bounds
        landsat = src.read()[0, :, :]
        landsat = np.ma.masked_where(landsat <= 0,
                                     landsat,
                                     copy=True)
        landsat = (landsat - np.min(landsat)) / (np.max(landsat) - np.min(landsat))

    proj = ccrs.LambertConformal(central_latitude=40,
                                 central_longitude=-110)

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 16))
    ax = plt.axes(projection=proj)
    ax.set_extent([-110.8, -110.4, 45.3, 45.6], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())

    shape_feature = ShapelyFeature(Reader(shapefile).geometries(),
                                   ccrs.PlateCarree(), edgecolor='blue')
    ax.add_feature(shape_feature, facecolor='none')
    ax.imshow(landsat, transform=ccrs.UTM(raster_crs['zone']),
              cmap='inferno',
              extent=(left, right, bottom, top))
    plt.savefig('surface_temp.png')


feature_source = 'fields.shp'
raster_source = 'surface_temperature_32612.tif'

cartopy_example(raster_source, feature_source)
```

The trick with Cartopy is to remember to use the `projection` keyword for your axes object, as this renders the map in a nice projection of your choice (LCC in my case). Use `transform` keyword to indicate what projection system your data is in, so Cartopy knows how to render it.

[image: Landsat surface temperature]

Comment: this is a great soln! Do you know if there is a way that the raster still shows up if the `facecolor='white'`  or some other color for the cartopy vector features? I find that the cartopy features are drawn at the top

Comment: This worked well but I had to change raster_crs['zone'] to just 12, the utm zone number for it to work. Has there been some change that causes raster_crs['zone'] to no longer work? Is there any other way we can get the zone number?

Answer (score -1):

No need of `rasterio`. Get a bluemarble image, then plot it.

Here is the working code:

```
import cartopy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.InterruptedGoodeHomolosine())
# source of the image:
# https://eoimages.gsfc.nasa.gov/images/imagerecords/73000/73909/world.topo.bathy.200412.3x5400x2700.jpg
fname = "./world.topo.bathy.200412.3x5400x2700.jpg"
img_origin = 'lower'
img = plt.imread(fname)
img = img[::-1]
ax.imshow(img, origin=img_origin, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), extent=[-180, 180, -90, 90])

ax.coastlines()
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.BORDERS)

ax.set_global()
plt.show()
```

The output plot:

[image: interrupted_projection]

Comment: Yeah, but I need this to work on extremely high-resolution topography for the moon (as well as the earth example in the notebook), and your solution won't do that. I didn't just decide to use rasterio because I like cutting and pasting code. :)

Comment: @DoctorMohawk You didn't mention the required resolution and the moon may be ++. I will wait and see the accepted answer.

Comment: While you're correct that I didn't mention the required resolution, I *did* specifically say I wanted to render a rasterio raster on a Cartopy GeoAxes.

Comment: How about "...I wonder if there's some way to do what I'm trying to do ..."